# AWS Pinpoint fails to send emails to SignInWithApple users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, apple-sign-in, aws-pinpoint

I am using AWS Cognito to manage my user pools. Users can signup using email, Apple, Facebook & Google.
Email registered users are required to confirm their account (through email verification). I want to have the same behaviour for social signup but unsuccessful (will leave this issue for another question).
I am using AWS Pinpoint to reach my user pool by email. When creating a campaign only users who did signup with email & password receives the email (not social users), and I don't understand why. Any idea of what could be the cause of the problem, or perhaps the solution?

Additional information:

- Tried verify social user's emails manually (using aws admin privileges) => users still don't receive emails.
- Did export my segment to csv, and apple relay email endpoints are in the segment (with an Active status) => but still no email received by social users (not forwarded for this case)

Thank you all for you assistance

Comment: Have you make attribute mapping :
For User pool attribute, choose the user pool attribute from the drop-down list that you want to map to the social identity provider attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am already having that set (I am mapping email and name)